# Problema com CORS utilizando Vue + Laravel (só funciona metodo GET)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, cors

- **Vue**: CLI 3
- **Laravel**: 6

Ao tentar utilizar requisições diferentes de GET (ex.: POST, DELETE), recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/teste' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

**Configuração do axios:**

```
import axios from "axios"

export const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
    },

})
```

**Exemplo das requisições:**

```
    get: () => {
        return http.get('teste')
    },
    store: (data) => {
        return http.post('teste', data)
    }
```

Para configurar o CORS, utilizei o seguinte pacote:
https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

**Configuração do CORS:**

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['api/*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => false,
    'max_age' => false,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```

Também tentei utilizar o pacote https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors, mas tive o mesmo resultado: somente o método GET funciona.

Obs.: consigo utilizar outros métodos através do Postman, por exemplo.

Imagem com os headers + erro:

[image: Imagem com os headers + erro]

Comment: Uma sugestão se queres rodar tudo na tua maquina tem extensões do chrome que liberam o cors depois tu volta quando for navegar na internet. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=cors+extension+chrome Se o problema persistir no servidor ai é permissões do PHP ou um ta HTTPS e o outro HTTP. mas tem outras possibilidades também...

Comment: Precisa de pacote para fazer isso? Coloca os headers que quer enviar de cors no `bootstrap/app.php` e já resolve isso, sem precisar de pacote.

Comment: Esse erro provavelmente pode ser resolvido no laravel, no arquivo `app/Http/Kernel.php` você pode adicionar ao array `$middleware`a classe `\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\Cors::class` ou então a classe `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class` que vem da biblioteca que vc instalou.

Comment: Amigo, tente adicionar esses seguintes headers: 

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Acess-Control-Allow-Headers: Acess-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type, Acess-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization");`

Estava com um erro semelhante e resolveu.